# Why doesn't resharper suggest removing redundant access modifiers?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, access-modifiers

Resharper is superb, as any fule kno.

However, if I declare a method such:

```
private void MethodName() { //code in here }
```

or an enum:

```
public enum SomeEnum { Value1, Value2 }
```

Resharper doesn't suggest removing the redundant access modifiers... why not?

Comment: It's far better to be explicit about these things. It avoids confusion and costs very little time while editing and no time while compiling.

Comment: Please don't remove these from your code! They're not the same in every language, and it's always better to make them explicit. This is a case where redundancy hurts *nothing* and actually improves readability.

Comment: Hmmm, debatable, as it's rather subjective what is 'better' to make explicit and what isn't.

Comment: Good question, but the modifier `public` in your example is **not** redundant. Your enum would be `internal` (if it's not inside some other type) or `private` (if it's nested inside e.g. a class) by default. The **members** of the enum are public by default, and it's even illegal to specify the access of them: `enum SomeEnum { public Value1, public Value2, }` won't compile.

Comment: I didn't like the first two replies to this, @nicodemus13. Your comment is correct: "better" is in the eye of the beholder. I'd like an OPTION to do things like this. There are tons of options. I found this question trying to make it so redundant parentheses would throw a warning. Same kind of deal: I want it to do so. I just want to know if that's an option. Right now it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't suggest removing redundant comments either. It recognises that some of the content of the code file, while technically redundant to a compiler, enhances code readability, and hence maintainability.

Comment: When you say 'redundant' comments, I presume you mean empty comments ;)  It's not yet clever enough to figure out that some's programmer's comment doesn't actually have any semantic value!

Comment: No, I simply meant that both comments and access modifiers (if it's the default) are equally redundant to the compiler. They're only informative to the programmer. Incidentally, Resharper DOES suggest removing empty comments, as it knows they're redundant to the programmer too!

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, because you configured it like this: ReSharper -> Options -> Languages -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Use explicit private / internal modifier

Comment: It's the default.  Thanks for the note, though.

Comment: In Resharper Ultimate 10, it looks like the path to this is now:

ReSharper -> Options -> **Code Editing** -> C# -> **Code Style** -> **Modifiers** -> **Prefer explicit/implicit internal/private modifier for types.**

Answer (score 1):

By default not having an access modifier is a StyleCop violation (if you're picky enough to turn ALL the rules on).

Comment: So why bother having defaults?

Comment: @nicodemus13: For those of us who are lazy, under time pressure, or don't care about StyleCop at its pickiest!